# Incompatible types - Required Long Found void + Optional<>

Tags: java, option-type, incompatibility

The entire first line is red underlined with the message: `Incompatible types. Required: Java.lang.Long. Found: void.`

```
Long userId = request.ifPresent(x -> x.getUsers().getId());
Optional<Users> employee = usersRepository.findOne(userId);
```

My findOne method:

```
// fetch an individual user by ID
Optional<Users> user = usersRepository.findOne(1L);
log.info("User found with findOne(1L):");
log.info("--------------------------------");
log.info(user.toString());
log.info("");
```

Users POJO:

```
    @Entity
    public class Users {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private Long id;
    ...
        public Long getId() {
                return id;
            }
    ...
    }
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `request` is `java.util.Optional`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other posters point out, you're trying to use `ifPresent` the wrong way.

Assuming that `request` is an `Optional<Request>`, you should probably be doing something like:

```
Optional<Long> userIdMaybe = request.map(r -> r.getUsers().getId());
Optional<Users> employee = userIdMaybe.flatMap(usersRepository::findOne);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming request is an Optional [`ifPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) consumes a value and returns void.

The compiling is correctly telling you that you cannot assign void to a Long.